# How can I add styles to dynamically added table cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my program I have a table that, when loaded, has jQuery add some styles/classes to the table cells and table headers.

Everything works fine until rows are added via functionality on the rest of the page.  Instead of adding the classes to the table cell during addition, is it possible to "listen" or fire some event that checks to see if child elements were added to the table.

Essentially, I want something functionally equivalent to this:

```
$("#table td").live("ready", function(){
 // do something
});
```

but the live/ready won't work on a table cell...  Any ideas?

Comment: can't you use the 'clone' method to get a TD with the styles already applied?

Comment: here is the problem, I don't have access to other parts of the page.  So when another piece adds a row to the table, they're just adding a bare-bones row, and I have to handle the styling of it...

Comment: So you don't have access to the style sheet either?

Comment: Not really.  I just have to assign the cells a class when they are added to the table, but I don't have access to the sections that add the row, or the style class being assigned to the row.  It's all a bit convoluted, especially taken out of context of the entire site...

Comment: If you can't modify the style sheet with something like `#table td {background:orange;}`, you can do so in javascript. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a setInterval and then check for the dynamic addition of table cells, if you don't have access to other parts in the page.

```
setInterval(function(){
    CheckStyles();
}, 1000);

function CheckStyles()
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: This is what I had been doing, but I felt like something could improve.  But perhaps it is the best approach after all...